# Consistency of a definition of triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm writing some notes about geometry in $\Bbb R^2$ and I have given these definitions:

- Given two different points $A$ and $B$, $X$ is a point of the segment $AB$ iff there exists some $t\in[0,1]$ such that $\overrightarrow{AX}=t\overrightarrow{AB}$. If $t$ isn't $0$ or $1$, we say that $X$ is an interior point of the segment.
- Given three non-colinear points $A$, $B$, $C$, the triangle $ABC$ is the union of the segments $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$ (the *sides* of the triangle) and the set of points $P$ such that there exists some interior point $X$ of the segment $AB$ such that $P$ is an interior point of the segment $CX$.

Now I want to prove the consistency of the definition when we change the side, that is, I want to prove that if $P$ meets the given condition, then there exists some interior point $Y$ in the segment $BC$ such that $P$ is an interior point of $AY$.

I have been "playing" with vectors for hours, avoiding using the coordinates of the vectors explicitly. I find two reasons. First: this should work at every Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$, and second, using the coordinates, equations of sides, etc, would make the proof somewhat horrible. But I couldn't catch the point so far... quite literally.

*Note:* moduli, dot product and angles are defined, but I couldn't figure out how to use them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought: for any point $O$ in the plane, can you prove that the triangle $ABC$ is precisely the set of the points $X$ in the plane such that $\vec{OX}=\alpha\vec{OA}+\beta\vec{OB}+\gamma\vec{OC}$ for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in[0,1], \alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$? Then this is symmetrical in $A,B,C$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for the idea, but the notes are for a High School student.. I find your definition just above his intuition. But if there is no better option for me, I'll consider it. +1 to your comment.